# Converting MySQL result array to JSON

Tags: php, json, mysqli, resultset

I want to convert my database query's result array to JSON format in PHP. Here is my code:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

I want to convert `$row` to JSON format and pass the JSON data to a jQuery plugin.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

`json_encode` is available in php > 5.2.0:

`echo`[`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)`($row);`

Comment: Hint: Use `JSON.parse(response)` to decode in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6):

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Data not found."); 
$rows=array(); 
while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
$rows[]=$r;
}
header("Content-type:application/json"); 
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Please, provide some additional information along with your answer.