# Convert array into json array using php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I have a PHP array like below:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [area] => Arappalayam
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [area] => Kalavasal
        )

)
```

Now, I need to convert this array into Json array like below :

```
    $local_source = [
    {
    id: 1,
    area: "Arappalayam"
    }, {
    id: 2,
    area: "Kalavasal"
    }
];
```

I have tried below code to convert json array in php

```
$availableArea = array_slice($areas[0],0);
return json_encode($availableArea);
```

But It is not working, any ideas>?

The result came as like [{"id":"1","area":"Arappalayam"},{"id":"2",area:"Kalavasal"}]; but i want [{id:1,area:"Arappalayam"},{id:2,area:"Kalavasal"}];

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122233/convert-php-result-array-to-json

Comment: The result came as like [{"id":"1","area":"Arappalayam"},{"id":"2",area:"Kalavasal"}]; 
but i want [{id:1,area:"Arappalayam"},{id:2,area:"Kalavasal"}];

Comment: The problem is that you don't want property names quoted and integers as strings?

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use `array_splice()`. Just use:

```
json_encode($myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

simply use `json_encode`

```
$local_source = json_encode($array);
```

check docs http://pk1.php.net/json_encode

and when decode it back to php array

```
$array = json_decode($local_source,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

1)
Your `"id":"1"` but not `"id":1` is because your value in PHP are really strings, not int.
Convert them using intval() will have a different result.

2)
No. You cannot generate `id:` rather then `"id":`, because keys are quoted string in standard [JSON specification](http://www.json.org/). Beside, there are Javascript reserved words could be be key in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow below given PHP example

```
$area = array('0' => array('id' => "1",'area' => 'Arappalayam'),
        '1' => array('id' => "2",'area' => 'Kalavasal')
        );

//callback function to do conversion
function convert($value){

  //convert only ID into integer 
  $value['id'] = intval($value['id']);

  return $value;
}   

$area = array_map('convert',$area); 
echo json_encode($area);
```