# Outputting SQL query as line by line JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, count, grouping

My SQL query is selecting date and doing a count, as well as grouping by date.

I don't know how to output line by line JSON output.

```
 $sql = "SELECT DATE(timestamp), COUNT(eventid)
 FROM `tablex`
 WHERE timestamp >= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 30 day)
 GROUP BY DATE(timestamp) ";

 $stream = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);


if (mysqli_num_rows($stream) > 0) {

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stream)) {

     // Is this where I should echo JSON? 
     // The problem is I'm not retrieving records but count and doing
     // a grouping

     }}
```

Comment: Can you show format which you want as o/p?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert php result array to json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122233/convert-php-result-array-to-json)

Comment: Output format should be like:

[{
  "timestamp": "2015-02-20",
  "count": 417
}]

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqli_fetch_array()`, also take the count with `mysql_num_rows()`:

```
$sql = "SELECT DATE(timestamp), COUNT(eventid)
 FROM `tablex`
 WHERE timestamp >= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 30 day)
 GROUP BY DATE(timestamp) ";

 $stream = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($stream) > 0) {
   $rowCount = mysql_num_rows($result);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
       // Process JSON here use $row[0], $row[1], and so
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you like to return as a JSON-string, you should always write your data into a single array, then use this nice little PHP-function called `json_encode()`. For example:

```
$sql = "SELECT
   DATE(timestamp) as date_timestamp,
   COUNT(eventid) as count_eventid
   FROM `tablex`
   WHERE timestamp >= date_sub(CURRENT_DATE, interval 30 day)
   GROUP BY DATE(timestamp);";

$stream = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

// prepare return array
$mydata = array(
    'eventcount' => 0
);

if (mysqli_num_rows($stream) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stream)) {
        // just collect your data here, do not JSONify here
        $mydata['eventcount'] += $row['count_eventid'];
    }
}
// We got all our data, so return JSON encoded array
echo json_encode($mydata);
```

You will get something like

```
{"eventcount":"1234"}
```

Comment: I get {"eventcount":0} as output. How do I incl. timestamp alongside eventcount?

Comment: If yout get 0, then you most likely don't retrieve any rows at all. You should first check if your SQL statement retrieves any records.

You may also want to try this:

    $mydata = array(
    );
    if (mysqli_num_rows($stream) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stream)) {
            // group counts by date
            $mydata[$row['date_timestamp']] = $row['count_eventid'];
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get an output:

```
$stream = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$lines = array();
while($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stream)) {
      $llines[] = $line;
}

print json_encode($lines);
```