# How to convert array into json

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have this type of Array

```
   Array
(
    [0] => Samy Jeremiah,55
    [1] => Nelson Owen,93
    [2] => McMaster Ashlie,88
    [3] => Marsh Harlow,97
    [4] => Macfarquhar Aiden,95
    [5] => Lowe Sophie,91
);
```

I need to convert this array into following type of json

```
data: [     
        ['Samy Jeremiah',55 ],      
        ['Nelson Owen',93 ],    
        ['McMaster Ashlie',88 ] , 
        ['Marsh Harlow',97 ] ,  
        ['Macfarquhar Aiden',95 ],  
        ['Lowe Sophie',91 ]   
     ]
```

Comment: Use `json_encode`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert php result array to json](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122233/convert-php-result-array-to-json)

Comment: i used json_encode($array);

Comment: shows wrong format

Comment: ["Samy Jeremiah,55","Nelson Owen,93","McMaster Ashlie,88","Marsh Harlow,97","Macfarquhar Aiden,95","Lowe Sophie,91"

Comment: @RivnatNasah User question and your answer is different. Read it Again

Comment: I can get this much but this is not my need {"data":["Samy Jeremiah,55","Nelson Owen,93","McMaster Ashlie,88","Marsh Harlow,97","Macfarquhar Aiden,95","Lowe Sophie,91"]}

Comment: What is your demand is not a  valid json format.

Comment: Are you trying it in your Ajax success?

Comment: Yes obviously correct !

Comment: If I understand correctly, `echo json_encode(array_column(array_map(function ($value) { return explode(',', $value); }, $data), 1, 0));` shuld give you a json encoded array with the name as the key, and the number as the value

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
    $yourArray = array(
        '0' => 'Samy Jeremiah,55', 
        '1' => 'Nelson Owen,93', 
        '2' => 'McMaster Ashlie,88', 
        '3' => 'Marsh Harlow,97', 
        '4' => 'Macfarquhar Aiden,95', 
        '5' => 'Lowe Sophie,91', 
    );

    #Check output 01
    //print_r($yourArray);

    foreach ($yourArray as $value) {                
        $explodeValue = explode( ',', $value );    
        $newName []= array($explodeValue[0] => $explodeValue[1]);
    }
    #Check output 02
    //print_r($newName);

    #Check output 03
    echo(json_encode($newName));
?>
```

[PHPFiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/e04dced7fd2d218f34fc806e4cdfe810)

---

**Output 01**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Samy Jeremiah,55 
    [1] => Nelson Owen,93 
    [2] => McMaster Ashlie,88 
    [3] => Marsh Harlow,97 
    [4] => Macfarquhar Aiden,95 
    [5] => Lowe Sophie,91 
)
```

**Output 02**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( [Samy Jeremiah] => 55 ) 
    [1] => Array ( [Nelson Owen] => 93 ) 
    [2] => Array ( [McMaster Ashlie] => 88 ) 
    [3] => Array ( [Marsh Harlow] => 97 ) 
    [4] => Array ( [Macfarquhar Aiden] => 95 ) 
    [5] => Array ( [Lowe Sophie] => 91 ) 
)
```

**Output 03**

```
[
    {"Samy Jeremiah":"55"},
    {"Nelson Owen":"93"},
    {"McMaster Ashlie":"88"},
    {"Marsh Harlow":"97"},
    {"Macfarquhar Aiden":"95"},
    {"Lowe Sophie":"91"}
]
```

Comment: @Boominathan check this

Answer (score 0):

Your desired result is an array of arrays. You have to split each entry of your array into 2 entities and push them as an array into a new array, then json_encode() the new array.

This php-snippet only works, if your input is consistantly an array of strings, containing each one comma as separator between name and int-value:

```
$arr2 = array();
foreach($arr1 as $e) {
  list($name, $val) = explode(',', $e);
  $arr2[] = array($name, (int)$val);
}
echo json_encode($arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
$data = array('Samy Jeremiah,55', 'Nelson Owen,93', 'McMaster Ashlie,88', 'Marsh Harlow,97', 'Macfarquhar Aiden,95', 'Lowe Sophie,91');
    $res = array();
    foreach($data as $e) {
      $list = explode(',', $e);
      $res[] = array($list[0], $list[1]);
    }
    echo json_encode(['data'=>$arr2]);
```

**Output**

```
{"data":[
         ["Samy Jeremiah",55],
         ["Nelson Owen",93],
         ["McMaster Ashlie",88],
         ["Marsh Harlow",97],
         ["Macfarquhar Aiden",95],
         ["Lowe Sophie",91]
        ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the `json_encode` you can achieve what you want.

Suppose your array name is `$arr`, so now apply the `json_encode`.

```
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$arr)); //your json will be print here
```

Real time Example:

```
$arr = array('Samy Jeremiah,55', 'Nelson Owen,93', 'McMaster Ashlie,88', 'Marsh Harlow,97', 'Macfarquhar Aiden,95', 'Lowe Sophie,91');
$new_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $k => $val){
    $na = explode(",", $val);
    $na[0] = "'".$na[0]."'";
    $value = implode(",", $na);
    $new_arr[$k] = $value;
}

echo json_encode(array("data" => $new_arr));
```

Comment: I used json_encode($array);  Its showing wrong format ["Samy Jeremiah,55","Nelson Owen,93","McMaster Ashlie,88","Marsh Harlow,97","Macfarquhar Aiden,95","Lowe Sophie,91"

Comment: I can get this much but this is not my need {"data":["Samy Jeremiah,55","Nelson Owen,93","McMaster Ashlie,88","Marsh Harlow,97","Macfarquhar Aiden,95","Lowe Sophie,91"]}

Comment: I need to put this json in jqchart they mentioned this type of json format thats why i asked to convert in this format  example jqchart code is this $('#columchart').jqChart({
      title: {  },
      animation: { duration: 1 },
      shadows: {
        enabled: true
      },
      series: [
      {
        type: 'column',
        title: 'Term 1',
        fillStyle:'#3980b5',

        data: [       
     ['Samy Jeremiah',55 ] ,
 ['Nelson Owen',93 ] ,
 ['McMaster Ashlie',88 ] ,
 ['Marsh Harlow',97 ] ,
 ['Macfarquhar Aiden',95 ] ,
 ['Lowe Sophie',91 ] 
        ]
      },