# Php array conver to C# json

Tags: c#, php

How can I convert php array to c# string(xml or json)?

```
  [ID] => 1
  [CreditNo] => 2
  [Date] => 2017-06-15
```

I have found some source but they dont work

Comment: Show us what you've tried and how it failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting PHP result array to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122233/converting-php-result-array-to-json)

Comment: @KrisRoofe to my mind it is not duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122233/converting-php-result-array-to-json

Comment: @Bassie  I have used https://www.codeproject.com/script/articles/articleversion.aspx?aid=292712&av=433386  link but  i get error

Comment: It looks like the link @KrisRoofe provided explains well how to convert a php array to JSON. I tried it on http://phpfiddle.org/ and it seems to work. If that's not what you're wanting you may need to rephrase the question.

Comment: I want to do it  with c# codes

Comment: @Sake Do you have an example input which produces the error?

Answer (score 1):

Convert the json to xdocument and get the results

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(JsonReaderWriterFactory.CreateJsonReader(
    Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonString), new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()));

var resultlist=xml.Descendants("item"); // to get the direct node value result as list
```