# Php processing json output

Tags: php, json

Am trying to produce a json object ouput of the following

```
{
 name: 'creditor',
  y: 5600
}, 
{
 name: 'Supplier',
  y: 2400,
 },
```

In my php i have

```
public function getTotalInspected($ts1, $ts2){
  $inspectiondata = [];
   $truck_categories = TblTruckSubtypes::find()->all();

    foreach ($truck_categories as $truck_category) {
       $name =  $truck_category["description"];
       $trucks = TblTrucks::find()->
               where(['truck_category'=>$truck_category["id"]])->count();
       $inspectiondata[] =  ["name"=>$name,'y'=> $trucks];
     }

  return $inspectiondata;

 }
```

The above produces an output of the form

```
 {
 "name": 'creditor',
  "y": 5600
}, 
{
 "name": 'Supplier',
  "y": 2400,
 },
```

Note the name from the desired output and "name" in the output.

How can i get the desired output above.

Comment: The desired output is an invalid JSON - the keys are strings, and strings must be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: am trying to produce data for  https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Comment: You can encode the array with `json_encode`, escape JavaScript characters with `json_encode`, again, then use `JSON.parse` function on the client side, e.g. `var series = JSON.parse(<?= json_encode(json_encode(['name' => 'creator', 'y' => 2400])); ?>)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting PHP result array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122233/converting-php-result-array-to-json)  Do not try to roll your own `json_encode()`, just call the function and be done.  Please research more before posting.

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov after jsonParse am ending up with an array, how do i then convert the array to object

Answer (score -1):

Try with json_encode() and preg_replce()

```
$inspectiondata= json_encode($inspectiondata);

$inspectiondata   = preg_replace('/"([a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-
                                   9_]*)":/','$1:',$inspectiondata);
```