# how to delete indexes on multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

i have this multidimensional array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
       (
          [firstName] => Hadi
          [lastName] => Pratama
          [age] => 22
       )

    [1] => Array
       (
          [firstName] => Jefri
          [lastName] => Ronaldo
          [age] => 21
       )

    [2] => Array
       (
          [firstName] => Rizky
          [lastName] => Aulia
          [age] => 20
       )
)
```

i want to put them into indexed array like this.

```
Array = ({"firstName":"Hadi","lastName":"Pratama","age":"22"},{"firstName":"Jefri","lastName":"Ronaldo","age":"21"},
{"firstName":"Rizky","lastName":"Aulia","age":"20"});
```

help me please.

Comment: [json_encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO.  Add code (edit your question) with what you have tried, otherwise your question may be closed and/or voted down.

Comment: dupe : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122233/converting-php-result-array-to-json

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting PHP result array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122233/converting-php-result-array-to-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure quite what your question is here (please clarify by editing your post).

Your output does not look like a Php array.  More like JSON.

When you say remove indexes, could this be from having non sequential 0 counted indexes?

See below:

```
<?php

$people =
[
    [
        'name'=>'fred',
        'family'=>'flintstones'
    ],
    [
        'name'=>'barney',
        'family' => 'rubble'
    ],
    [
        'name'=> 'wilma',
        'family' => 'flintstones'
    ]
];

var_dump(json_encode($people));
unset($people[1]);
var_dump(json_encode($people));
var_dump(json_encode(array_values($people)));
```

Output:

```
string(116) "[{"name":"fred","family":"flintstones"},{"name":"barney","family":"rubble"},{"name":"wilma","family":"flintstones"}]"
string(88) "{"0":{"name":"fred","family":"flintstones"},"2":{"name":"wilma","family":"flintstones"}}"
string(80) "[{"name":"fred","family":"flintstones"},{"name":"wilma","family":"flintstones"}]"
```

You can use array_values to reindex arrays before encoding to JSON to 'remove' those indexes, and turn into a list of objects.

Comment: thank you for answering my question. to be honest this array is a json file that has been decoded and then I do some array filters and then the index appears. I don't know how to restore it to the previous format

Answer (score 0):

> [**json_encode()**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)  : Returns the JSON representation of a value

```
echo json_encode($a);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/EgOtE

Answer (score 0):

## Question

Your array already has the correct dimensions, just run `json_encode($array);` over it and you will have the result you're looking for.

If you want to use an associative array, you'll have to be a bit more creative:

```php
$result = [];
foreach($array as $index) {
   $result[$index['firstName']] = $index;
}

var_dump($result);
```

## Result:

```
Array
(
    [Hadi] => Array
       (
          [firstName] => Hadi
          [lastName] => Pratama
          [age] => 22
       )

    [Jefri] => Array
       (
          [firstName] => Jefri
          [lastName] => Ronaldo
          [age] => 21
       )

    [Rizky] => Array
       (
          [firstName] => Rizky
          [lastName] => Aulia
          [age] => 20
       )
)
```